# Given two postive integers m and n, sketch the graph of $f(x)=\{mx\}\{nx\}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Note that $f(x)=\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}$.I think that the problem can be simplified if we find an expression for $f(x)=\{mx\}\{nx\}$, where $m$ and $n$ are Integers. Suppose $m<n$, then ${1\over m}>{1\over n}.$So the period of $g(x)=\{mx\}$ is smaller that the period of $h(x)=\{nx\}$. The functions h and g intersect only at the origin, so $f(0)=0.$ The real problem occurs when in the interval $I=[1/m,1/n]$.

Comment: $m < n$ implies $\frac 1n < \frac 1m$.

Comment: @Crostul Sorry for th typo. I made an edit.

Comment: I think converting {mx}=mx-[mx] might be useful.